# Best way to match two records in the same table in pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :other_foo, class_name: 'Foo'
end
```

If I update `other_foo`, I want the matching `Foo` instance to update too, to reference the first one.

Is there a preferred way (apart from callbacks) to do that or do I have to remember about that and make two updates manually?

Answer (score 0):

Use `touch: true`...

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :other_foo, class_name: 'Foo', touch: true
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch

Comment: How does it solve my problem? It can only update `datetime` columns.